# How to make SiO₂ hydrophobic aqueous-solution

Tags: aqueous-solution

I bought 100g of SiO₂ hydrophobic of 20 nanometers. I'm trying to make my own "car body wax". This "wax" that you can buy on the internet allows to make water repellent on car bodies : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRtNpGQM53E

I did a quick test by mixing a few grams of SiO₂ with water and then put on my car body. It didn't work, no hydrophobia.

Would you know how to use this powder from SiO₂ to make a hydrophobic liquid ?

Comment: Who makes wax by putting hydrophobic components into water ? Do you want hydrophilic wax ? You are supposed to use some hydrophobic matrix for this hydrophobized ( silanized? )  SiO2.

Comment: This SiO2-based liquid can be found on the internet and in various car stores.
The final goal is to create a hydrophobic film on the car body so that the water runs off instead of staying on the body.

On the site of a French manufacturer, it is indicated : 
"Our products are liquid solutions based on water or ethanol (alcohol) in which the active substance, Silicon Dioxide (SiO2), is immersed". => https://www.nano-protection.fr/content/6-faq

Comment: I suppose it is not just water and silanized SiO2. there is  know-how what to add as a thin film of SiO2 binder after water evaporates. "based on"

Comment: Maybe, I don't know the solution used to "assemble" them unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The claims in the video are surely exaggerated: protection for 6 months? In a garage, perhaps.

The video claims that the hydrophobic silica - $SiO_2$ - is activated by water. The final product is applied to a wet car body with water droplets severely beaded up - i.e., already hydrophobic from the pretreatment washing agent and rub. So, the hydrophobic agent reacts with water on the car to repel water - but is already in an aqueous solution in the bottle?

My guess is that the actual process is 1) the wash which includes a hydrophobizing surfactant, perhaps a silyl ether, 2) a rub with a cloth containing some agent like a high m.w. silicone oil (promotes water beading), followed by 3) the application of fairy dust (informal term for a product that has more imaginary power than chemical activity) in water containing some slightly odoriferous (but safe) solvent. Perhaps it also contains some silyl ether or other silicone oil-type surfactant.

The main character in the video did a great job of showing how to use the manufacturer's product, and it is sure to have some advantage - he said it was a time saver. It also seemed to have the advantage of allowing you to rub your car gently and love it, and beautify it with a wash and rinse. But I was not convinced by Dave, the "chemist". I think he was a mechanic or a salesman. Good graphics, but not really believable. I also liked the spray bottles: very nice misting (not squirting), which implies low surface tension.

A related product called Rain-X is a silyl ether in alcohol. It was wiped onto dry windshields to provide a hydrophobic surface. It had to be applied evenly and very thin, but beaded up water fantastically! Any thick portions also resulted in beading up, but these thicker zones were soft and deformed a tiny bit, increasing the hysteresis and resistance to easy movement. So the beads didn't run, they built up and actually decreased visibility.

Comment: I have tested this kind of product and I guarantee you that it is not a "fairy powder".
It works really great. Just put it on the body and rub it until it's dry. The body is also shinier where the product is applied. The solution contains no silicone oil and is really fluid like water. In fact, it is said that you can drink it because the components are harmless.

Comment: Experiments are the best proof. I acknowledge your results and have no evidence of the opposite. But I still wouldn't drink it. I'll look around to see if it is available here.